# How does energy stay conserved if the force is time dependent and doesn't depend on location?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

While reading The Theoretical Minimum for Classical Mechanics the author said that the derivative of the potential energy is equals the force and showed this equation describing the potential energy of a single particle in a one dimensional space:
$$F(x)=-\frac{dV(x)}{dx}$$
He said that the force here depends on the location of the particle. He continued:
$$E=T+V$$
$$\dot{E}=\dot{T}+\dot{V}=mva+\frac{dV(x)}{dt}=mva+\frac{dV(x)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$\dot{E}=mva+\frac{dV(x)}{dx}v=v(ma+\frac{dV(x)}{dx})=0$$
And that's how he proved that energy is conserved, but what if the the force is time dependent then $F(t)=\frac{dV(t)}{dt}$ and continuing with the same path I get this:
$$\dot{E}=mva+\frac{dV(t)}{dt}\neq0$$
What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: you arent wrong; if the forces are time dependent then in general energy is not conserved. You have to have special kinds of forces in order for time dependent forces to conserve energy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do nothing wrong. If the forces depends on time explicitly, energy is not conserved in general.

There is a deeper connection here: Energy is the conserved quantity corresponding to time-translation symmetry (as momentum is the conserved quantity corresponding to spatial translation symmetry). If your force now depends on time explicitly, the motion of your test particle (starting from the same position), will depend on the starting time – so the time translation symmetry is broken by that explicit dependency.

The correspondence between (continuous) symmetries and conserved quantities is known as [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) and a corner stone of theoretical physics.

---

A small note on what I mean with explicit dependency: Of course you can always can write down a function of force over time $F(t)$, if however this can be written as $F\big(x(t), v(t)\big)$, where $x(t)$ and $v(t)$ are the solution to your equation of motion, then there will be no *explicit* time dependency, because if you move your initial setup to another time, the force curve will just shift in time with your initial conditions. So the time translation symmetry is upheld.

Comment: Where can I read more about this topic as I'm not familiar with Noether's theorem?

Comment: I would expect a book that calls itself "theoretical minimum" to contain a section on Noether's theorem later on. If you are not familiar with Lagrangian mechanics (a variational formulation of classical mechanics), you will have to learn that to move beyond an informal understanding of the theorem.

Comment: (I just checked: Landau/Lifshitz I does not mention Noether's theorem – but derives conservation energy, momentum and angular momentum from the Lagrangian formalism as special cases, roughly like the general form of the theorem is derived).

Comment: (Also, note that I linked to the Wikipedia article for Noether's theorem in my answer, although I can see how this may not be really helpful, depending on your prior knowledge.)

Answer (score 1):

Your first three lines are correct. But your statement "if the force is time dependent then $F(t) = dV/dt$" is incorrect; that is not how forces and potentials work and is not even dimensionally compatible. The force is always the *spatial* derivative of the potential.

Also, if the potential energy function $V$ depends on time as well as space, then $$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}.$$ So your last line is incorrect; the correct statement is $\frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$. The other two terms still cancel as in the time-independent case.

Your takeaway conclusion that "Energy is not conserved if the potential energy function depends explicitly on time" is still correct.